# SQL BigQuery - SUM over ARRAY_AGG - Error: No matching signature for argument type: ARRAY

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

## I'm trying to run this line of code:

```
SUM(
array_agg(
        case when type = "jump" then 1 else 0 end
        )
    over (partition by case_id order by start_at_local_true_01
    ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
)
as jump_count_per_case_id_in_future,
```

### But I'm running into this error:

```
No matching signature for aggregate function SUM
for argument types: ARRAY<INT64>.
Supported signatures: SUM(INT64); SUM(FLOAT64); SUM(NUMERIC); SUM(BIGNUMERIC); SUM(INTERVAL) at [33:1]
```

## This is the table I'm starting with:

| Row | case_id | start_at_local_true_01 | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12123 | 2022-02-01 11:00:00 | null |
| 2 | 12123 | 2022-02-01 11:15:00 | run |
| 3 | 12123 | 2022-02-01 11:21:00 | jump |
| 4 | 12123 | 2022-02-04 11:31:00 | run |
| 5 | 12123 | 2022-02-05 11:34:00 | jump |
| 6 | 12555 | 2022-02-08 12:38:00 | credit |
| 7 | 12555 | 2022-02-01 11:15:00 | null |

### And this is the table I'd want to end with:

| Row | case_id | start_at_local_true_01 | type | **jump_count_per_case_id_in_future** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12123 | 2022-02-01 11:00:00 | null | **2** |
| 2 | 12123 | 2022-02-01 11:15:00 | run | **2** |
| 3 | 12123 | 2022-02-01 11:21:00 | **jump** | **2** |
| 4 | 55555 | 2022-02-04 11:31:00 | run | **0** |
| 5 | 12123 | 2022-02-05 11:34:00 | **jump** | **1** |
| 6 | 12123 | 2022-02-08 12:38:00 | credit | **0** |
| 7 | 55555 | 2022-02-01 11:15:00 | null | **0** |

#### This is my code so far (including sample table):

```
with data_table as(
    select * FROM UNNEST(ARRAY<STRUCT<
    case_id INT64, start_at_local_true_01 DATETIME, type STRING>>
    [
         (12123, DATETIME("2022-02-01 11:00:00"), null)
        ,(12123, DATETIME("2022-02-01 11:15:00"), 'run')
        ,(12123, DATETIME("2022-02-01 11:21:00"), 'jump')
        ,(55555, DATETIME("2022-02-04 11:31:00"), 'run')
        ,(12123, DATETIME("2022-02-05 11:34:00"), 'jump')
        ,(12123, DATETIME("2022-02-08 12:38:00"), 'credit')
        ,(55555, DATETIME("2022-02-01 11:15:00"), null)
    ]
    )
)

select 
data_table.*,

array_agg(
        IFNULL(type,"-")
        )
    over (partition by case_id order by start_at_local_true_01
    ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
as type_array_per_case_id,

array_agg(
        case when type = "jump" then 1 else 0 end
        )
    over (partition by case_id order by start_at_local_true_01
    ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
as type_array_per_case_id_to_numbers,

SUM(
array_agg(
        case when type = "jump" then 1 else 0 end
        )
    over (partition by case_id order by start_at_local_true_01
    ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
)
as jump_count_per_case_id_in_future,

from data_table
```

#### Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below instead

```
COUNTIF(type = "jump")
    over (partition by case_id order by start_at_local_true_01
    ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
)
as jump_count_per_case_id_in_future,
```

Comment: This is actually just part of my larger problem. And, sadly, it isn't working to solve my larger problem. I'll post another question about the larger problem soon.

Comment: I just created this to describe the next step in my larger problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71330324/sql-bigquery-countif-with-criteria-from-current-row-and-partitioned-rows