# SQL BigQuery - COUNTIF with criteria from current row and partitioned rows

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

## I'm running this line of code:

```
COUNTIF(
    type = "credit"
    AND 
    DATETIME_DIFF(credit_window_end, start_at_local_true_01, DAY) BETWEEN 0 and 5
    )
    over (partition by case_id order by start_at_local_true_01
    ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
as credit_count_per_case_id_in_future_and_within_credit_window,
```

### And I'm getting this

| Row | case_id | start_at_local_true_01 | type | credit_window_end | credit_count_per_case_id_in_future_and_within_credit_window |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12123 | 2022-02-01 11:00:00 | null | 2022-02-06 11:00:00 | 0 |
| 2 | 12123 | 2022-02-01 11:15:00 | run | null | 0 |
| 3 | 12123 | 2022-02-01 11:21:00 | jump | 2022-02-06 11:21:00 | 0 |
| 4 | 12123 | 2022-02-04 11:31:00 | run | 2022-02-09 11:31:00 | 0 |
| 5 | 12123 | 2022-02-05 11:34:00 | jump | null | 0 |
| 6 | 12123 | 2022-02-08 12:38:00 | credit | null | 0 |
| 7 | 12555 | 2022-02-01 11:15:00 | null | null | 0 |

### But I want this

| Row | case_id | start_at_local_true_01 | type | credit_window_end | credit_count_per_case_id_in_future_and_within_credit_window |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12123 | 2022-02-01 11:00:00 | null | 2022-02-06 11:00:00 | 0 |
| 2 | 12123 | 2022-02-01 11:15:00 | run | null | 0 |
| 3 | 12123 | 2022-02-01 11:21:00 | jump | 2022-02-06 11:21:00 | 0 |
| 4 | 12123 | 2022-02-04 11:31:00 | run | 2022-02-09 11:31:00 | ***1*** |
| 5 | 12123 | 2022-02-05 11:34:00 | jump | null | 0 |
| 6 | 12123 | ***2022-02-08 12:38:00*** | ***credit*** | null | 0 |
| 7 | 12555 | 2022-02-01 11:15:00 | null | null | 0 |

**The 4th row *should be* 1 because (from the 6th row) credit = credit AND DATETIMEDIFF(2022-02-08T12:38:00, 2022-02-04 11:31:00, DAY) between 0 and 5**

The calculation within the cell would look like this:

```
COUNTIF(
    run = credit    AND DATETIMEDIFF(2022-02-04 11:31:00, 2022-02-04T11:31:00, DAY ) between 0 and 5
    jump = credit   AND DATETIMEDIFF(2022-02-04 11:31:00, 2022-02-05T11:34:00, DAY ) between 0 and 5
    credit = credit AND DATETIMEDIFF(2022-02-04 11:31:00, 2022-02-08T12:38:00, DAY ) between 0 and 5
)

COUNTIF(
    false and false
    false and false
    true and true
)

COUNTIF(
    0
    0
    1
)
```

#### I think I know why, but I don't know how to fix it.

It's because the `DATETIME_DIFF` function is taking both values from the same row (from each partitioned row). The second element should stay the same (start_at_local_true_01). But I want the first element to be fixed to the **CURRENT ROW**'s credit_window_end (*not each partitioned row's credit_window_end*).

#### This is my code so far (including sample table):

```
with data_table as(
    select * FROM UNNEST(ARRAY<STRUCT<
    case_id INT64, start_at_local_true_01 DATETIME, type STRING, credit_window_end DATETIME>>
    [
         (12123, DATETIME("2022-02-01 11:00:00"), null,     DATETIME("2022-02-06 11:00:00"))
        ,(12123, DATETIME("2022-02-01 11:15:00"), 'run',    null)
        ,(12123, DATETIME("2022-02-01 11:21:00"), 'jump',   DATETIME("2022-02-06 11:21:00"))
        ,(12123, DATETIME("2022-02-04 11:31:00"), 'run',    DATETIME("2022-02-09 11:31:00"))
        ,(12123, DATETIME("2022-02-05 11:34:00"), 'jump',   null)
        ,(12123, DATETIME("2022-02-08 12:38:00"), 'credit', null)
        ,(12555, DATETIME("2022-02-01 11:15:00"), null,     null)
    ]
    )
)

select 
data_table.*,

COUNTIF(
    type = "credit"
    )
    over (partition by case_id order by start_at_local_true_01
    ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
as credit_count_per_case_id_in_future,

COUNTIF(
    type = "credit"
    AND 
    DATETIME_DIFF(start_at_local_true_01, credit_window_end, DAY) BETWEEN 0 and 5
    )
    over (partition by case_id order by start_at_local_true_01
    ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
as credit_count_per_case_id_in_future_and_within_credit_window,

--does not work. does not even run
-- DATETIME_DIFF(
-- credit_window_end,
-- array_agg(
--         IFNULL(start_at_local_true_01,DATETIME("2000-01-01 00:00:00"))
--         )
--     over (partition by case_id order by start_at_local_true_01 asc
--     ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
-- , DAY
-- )
-- as credit_count_per_case_id_in_future_and_within_credit_window_02,

from data_table
```

#### Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi OP, can you please explain further the reason why we are getting the `DATEDIFF` of `start_at_local_true_01` from row6 and `credit_window_end` from row4? Also, why is the value of COUNT must be put in row4 and not in row6? What is the logic behind that?

Comment: I want each row with a non-null `credit_window_end` to look forward in time to see if any future `type` associated with that `case_id` has a `type` = "credit". However, I don't want to look into the future forever, I only want to look between the datetime from **CURRENT ROW's** `start_at_local_true_01` to **CURRENT ROW's** `credit_window_end`.
DATETIME_DIFF is probably not the most efficient way. The COUNT_IF criteria could also be `type` = "credit" AND `start_at_local_true_01` BETWEEN **CURRENT ROW's** `start_at_local_true_01` AND **CURRENT ROW's** `credit_window_end`

Comment: If there's a way to specify the window_frame_clause in such a way as this, it would be ideal:  

COUNTIF(
    type = "credit"
    )
    over (partition by case_id order by start_at_local_true_01
    ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND **CURRENT ROW's** `credit_window_end`)
as credit_count_per_case_id_in_future,

Comment: @ScottB Sorry, I had a few typos in my descriptions and sample code. That must have made everything more confusing for you. They all should be fixed now.

Comment: I think there might have to be some sub select statement which does the work of checking if the future `start_at_local_true_01` is within range, but it would need to be per-row...

Comment: I figured it out. I just changed the window to: over (partition by `case_id` order by UNIX_MILLIS(TIMESTAMP(`start_at_local_true_01`))
RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 432000000 FOLLOWING)

Comment: Hi @Phil! That's great! Can you please post your solution as answer and accept it? This is for the benefit of the community that might encounter the same scenario in the future.

Answer (score 0):

As confirmed by @Phil in the comments, this was solved by changing the window to:

```
over (partition by case_id order by UNIX_MILLIS(TIMESTAMP(start_at_local_true_01)) RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 432000000 FOLLOWING)
```

Posting the answer as *community wiki* for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.